# How can I sort by a table column in varying cases (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-order-by, case-sensitive

How can I sort a table with a column of varchar2 with characters in varying cases (**UPPER** and **lower**)?

For example, when I do an order by of the Name column, I get the following results:

```
ANNIE
BOB
Daniel
annie
bob
```

What I want is something like this:

```
ANNIE
annie
BOB
bob
Daniel
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `lower(field)`, e.g.

```
select * from tbl order by lower(name)
```

If you need to address special characters for non-english languages then the other answers about NLSSORT may be what you need. If you don't I would try and KISS and use `lower()` as it is very easy to remember and use and be read by others (maintainability).

Comment: One thing to add would be that this would mean that unless there is a functional index on `lower(name)` a full table scan would be done with this query.

Comment: This query will always require a full table scan, with or without an ORDER BY. Usually the issue you're describing is more important with the WHERE clause.

Comment: @DCookie: do you want to bet? ;) e.g. try a functional index on `lower(name)` appended with all the columns from the table = full index scan, plus no sort :) - just sayin'

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but `UPPER()` would be the canonical, textbook way to do this. If a function-based index exists or will exist, you're more likely to find it on `UPPER()` than `LOWER()`.

Answer (score 13):

Another option is the use of the [NLSSORT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions113.htm#i78399) function to perform [linguistic sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG005):

```
SQL> with test as (select 'ANNIE' as col from dual
  2      union all select 'BOB' from dual
  3      union all select 'Daniel' from dual
  4      union all select 'annie' from dual
  5      union all select 'bob' from dual
  6      union all select 'Ångström' from dual
  7      union all select 'ångström' from dual)
  8  select col
  9  from test
 10  order by nlssort(col, 'NLS_SORT = WEST_EUROPEAN')
 11  /

COL
----------
Ångström
ångström
ANNIE
annie
BOB
bob
Daniel
```

The advantages are more flexibility. One can sort characters with accents as well as different cases together. One can choose to treat some characters in a language specific way by [specifying different values for NLS_SORT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/applocaledata.htm#i637232). Defines an order within the set of equivalent characters. So 'A' and 'a' are sorted together, but within the 'a's, the upper case comes first. Disadvantages  I expect that NLSSORT uses more CPU than LOWER, though I have not bench marked it. And NLSSORT will only use a prefix of [longer strings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions113.htm#i78399):

> The string returned, also known as the collation key, is of RAW data
>   type. The length of the collation key resulting from a given char
>   value for a given collation may exceed 2000 bytes, which is the
>   maximum length of the RAW value returned by NLSSORT. In this case,
>   NLSSORT calculates the collation key for a maximum prefix, or initial
>   substring, of char so that the calculated result does not exceed 2000
>   bytes. For monolingual collations, for example FRENCH, the prefix
>   length is typically 1000 characters. For multilingual collations, for
>   example GENERIC_M, the prefix is typically 500 characters. The exact
>   length may be lower or higher depending on the collation and the
>   characters contained in char.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#i1006421 for information on using indexes with linguistic sorting.

Answer (score 7):

If you're on relatively recent versions of Oracle, you should look at setting NLS_SORT/NLS_COMP, rather than using the LOWER() function.

If you don't want to globally affect the instance, you can use the NLSSORT() function to set the NLS_SORT for the scope of a specific query.

```
SQL> create table case_insensitive(a varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into case_insensitive values('D');

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> c/'D/'c
  1* insert into case_insensitive values('c')
SQL> /

1 row created.

SQL> c/'c/'B
  1* insert into case_insensitive values('B')
SQL> /

1 row created.

SQL> c/'B/'a
  1* insert into case_insensitive values('a')
SQL> /

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from case_insensitive;

A
----------
D
c
B
a

SQL> select * from case_insensitive order by a;

A
----------
B
D
a
c

SQL> select * from case_insensitive order by nlssort(a,'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI'); 

A
----------
a
B
c
D
```

A good example of this can be found [here.](http://www.orafaq.com/node/999)

Comment: Setting NLS_SORT/NLS_COMP will change the behavior of all queries. Which is great if that's what one wants. Not so great if it isn't.

Comment: Not necessarily.  I'll go back and edit my example to demonstrate.

Comment: NLSSORT & NLS_SORT are both defined by Oracle but are different things. The top of this answer referenced NLS_SORT, a parameter. However the code added after I commented uses the NLSSORT function. So if you originally meant NLSSORT, you are correct that my comment would not apply. NLSSORT http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions113.htm#SQLRF00678, NLS_SORT  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams152.htm#REFRN10127

Comment: The article I linked to covered both.  If you don't like my answer, you're free to vote it down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INITCAP` e.g.

```
SELECT fld FROM tbl ORDER BY INITCAP(fld) ASC;
```

Comment: There's no reason to provide an answer that is not better than an accepted one. Furthermore, initcap will not do (consider 'ANNA' and 'annie').

Answer (score -2):

You can use the Order by cluse for this

```
select col_name from table_name 
order by col_name ;
```