# Sql ORDER BY alphabetically no casesensitive

Tags: c#, sql, .net-1.1, asp.net-1.1

Today I encountered problem that causes difficulty for me to solve it.

In application I want to display records in aphabetical order thus in SQL statement I'am using ORDER BY, 
But it looks like CAPITAL letters are before lowercase letters so record starting with `Z` is before `a`.

This is example of my sql statement

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id= 5 ORDER BY name`

Do you have any ideas ? Can I sort data in DataTable object after retreiving it from database ? or can it be accomplished by more complex sql statement?

Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: your question looks an awful lot like this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788838/how-can-i-sort-by-a-table-column-in-varying-cases-oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for comparing text values is the *collation*; there are many many collations available in SQL Server, and most have both case-sensitive and case-insensitive options.

If you don't want to change the collation (in particular, if this applies only to specific cases), you can also use functions like `LOWER` / `UPPER`, but this cannot make efficient use of indexes. A hybrid approach is to store redundant information: store the original data in one column, and the standardized data (perhaps all lower-case-invariant) in a second column. Then you can index the two separately (as you need), and operate on either the original or standardized data. You would normally only *display* the original data, though. Persisted+calculated+indexed columns might work well here, as then it is impossible to get inconsistent data (the server is in charge of the calculated column).

Comment: Thanks for usefull informations, that maybe handy in future but at the moment I'm working on old existing data and i can't change data structure

Comment: @user3455363 oh, if only I had a 1GBP every time I heard "I need it to behave differently, but I'm not allowed to change anything". Well... if you don't change anything: expect it to stay the same ;p

Answer (score 6):

You can modify your SQL query in such a way that all capitals are transformed to lower before ordering

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 5 ORDER BY LOWER(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
   SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id= 5 ORDER BY LOWER(name)
```

OR

```
   SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id= 5 ORDER BY LCASE(name)
```

depending on which database you are using

Comment: I've tried LCASE , LOWER , UCASE,UPPER none of them worked it throws exception : System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: SQL: ORDER BY clause is invalid.
`string sql = "SELECT * FROM app_lookup WHERE nid="+npk+" ORDER BY LCASE(cdesc)";`

Answer (score 1):

You can perform ordering by providing case in SQL. Just do this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id= 5 ORDER BY UPPER(name)
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id= 5 ORDER BY UCASE(name)
```

Ordering will be done on upper case name while you result will be same as present in table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id= 5 ORDER BY name COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
```